# how to make proper selection through <xsl:value-of> tag?

Tags: html, xslt, abbr

following is my xml code:

```
<abbr>
<title>world health organization</title>who</abbr>
was founded in 1948.
```

in above code i want xslt output as:

```
<abbr title="world health organisation">who<abbr>
```

i wrote following XSLT code:

```
<xsl:template match ="abbr">
&lt;abbr title="<xsl:value-of select ="title"/>"&gt;
<xsl:value-of select ="."/>&lt;/abbr&gt;
</xsl:template>
```

and i got:

```
<abbr title="world health organization">
world health organizationwho</abbr>
```

where did i go wrong?

the output of

```
<xsl:value-of select"."/>
```

is

```
world health organisationwho
```

(world health organisation + who)

now, i dont want the first part.
how can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `title` is a child of `abbr`, `title`'s text is part of the string value of `abbr`. Please try this:

```
<xsl:template match ="abbr">
  <abbr title="{title}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
  </abbr>
</xsl:template>
```

Incidentally, are you using `xsl:output method="text"` in your XSLT? If you are using XSLT to produce XML, then you should use `method="xml"`. That's what XSLT was made for.